# How to route special egress traffic in azure kubernetes service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a web application in Azure kubernetes service, and a azure firewall which is used to secure all egress traffic because there is a route `Address: 0.0.0.0/32, Next hop: 10.0.2.4 (firewall private ip)`. The request and response traffic likes like:

```
User -------> Load Balancer Public Ip -------> Service --------> Pod ------> Firewall
```

From the diagram, we can find the response is routed to firewall, and azure firewall drops the response because it doesn't find valid TCP connection (asymmetric issue).

To solve it, I want to route the response traffic back to service and load balancer. How should I configure the route table? (I use kubelet network in the azure kubernetes service) Thanks

*I search in microsoft's public document, and only find that I need to request the firewall public ip, and use firewall's DNAT to translate traffic to service's external ip. However, because of our application's special requirement, we only can ask user to request the Load Balancer Public Ip. So the solution doesn't work for me.*